# ls: No such file or directory error

Tags: shell, files, ls

I am writing a very basic shell for my school. Even thought commands like "pwd" or "date" works when i try **"ls"** it shows me that 
**"ls: No such file or directory error"**

The code of my shell is bellow:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main()
{
int i;
char *line=(char *) malloc(1024*sizeof(char));

 while (1) {
   /* Print the command prompt */
   printf("$ ");
   fflush(stdout); /* Anagazei na trexei thn printf
   /* Read a command line */
   fgets(line, 1024, stdin);
  for(i=0;i<1024;i++){
   if(line[i]=='\n')
         {
           line[i]='\0';
         }
  }
  //printf("%s", line);
   pid_t pid = fork(); /* Dhmiourgei paidi. antigrafo diergasias. */
     if (pid==0){

           execlp(line,line);
      }
     else waitpid(pid,0,0);

  }
}
```

Comment: Looks like `ls` can not be found in the shells working directory. Try using the full path to `ls` like `/bin/ls`

Comment: No it doesn't work either. This is what shows up : /bin/ls: cannot access : No such file or directory

Comment: This worked for me too. But it is not the solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please read the man page for execlp carefully:

> The list of arguments must be terminated by a NULL pointer, and, since
>   these are variadic functions, this pointer must be cast (char *) NULL.

Using this line works for me:

```
execlp(line,line, (char*) NULL);
```

Your code also gave a warning for exactly this line (using GCC):

```
a.c: In function ‘main’:
a.c:26:12: warning: not enough variable arguments to fit a sentinel [-Wformat=]
            execlp(line,line);
            ^
```

Comment: Thank you so much. Since i am a rookie this helped a lot. have a nice day.